# How to convert multidimentional key value into single array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
{
        "image": "/b/l/black_10.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url_key": "printing-products"
    },
    {
        "position_back": "251,252"
    },
}
```

I need all the above array into a single array as below.

```
{
        "image": "/b/l/black_10.jpg"

        "url_key": "printing-products"

        "position_back": "251,252"

}
```

I need to convert it as a single array. I used the below code.

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $attr_code);
```

But I couldn't achieve expected output.

Comment: This is not an array. It looks more like json.

Comment: The first one is neither an array, nor a valid json

Comment: Can please add valid PHP input? until then, we want be able to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's look like json data. But not valid.

First make in valid. you can test on https://jsonlint.com/

After that using json_decode convert into array.

***You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://php.net/array_walk_recursive) to convert multidimensional key value into single array.***

```
   <?php
//Using json_decode convert json into array
$array = json_decode($json, true);

array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) use (&$final_array){$final_array[$key]=$item;});


/*use json_encode for json format
   echo json_encode($final_array);
 */

//For array you can use $final_array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_array);

?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/SULHA)

Comment: but json_encode converts it into string i need it to be an array.

Comment: Ok, I added both option.  use $final_array to get the result in array. Check the demo